# Web Page Resetting after scrolling Up SVG ( javascript )

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

My Webpage functions to change SVG size when the webpage is in either Landscape or Portrait

if webpage screen is resized then the appropriate SVG is loaded either: 
car1-landscape.svg
car1-portrait.svg

on iPhone using safari or chrome browser if the page is scrolled up
the webpage will be reloaded/restart

the webpage works fine on Desktop/Laptop only but restarting occurs on mobile devices.
restarting occurs in iPhone safari or chrome browsers

I use the line "window.location.href = window.location.href;" to restart page
so it can correctly load the appropriate landscape or portrait SVG

### my file

```
    <script>
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth)
    {

        // Portrait
        //alert ("Resized..P");
        document.write( '<object id=\"svg-objectp\" data=\"car1-portrait.svg\" type=\"image/svg+xml\"></object>' );
        document.getElementById("svg-objectp").style.width = "100%"; 
        document.getElementById("svg-objectp").style.height = "auto"; 

        }else{

        // Landscape
        //alert ("Resized..L");
        document.write( '<object id=\"svg-objectl\" data=\"car1-landscape.svg\" type=\"image/svg+xml\"></object>' );
        document.getElementById("svg-objectl").style.width = "100%"; 
        document.getElementById("svg-objectl").style.height = "auto"; 

    }   


    // Listen for resize changes
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        // Get screen size (inner/outerWidth, inner/outerHeight)

        //alert ("Resized..");
        window.location.href = window.location.href;

    }, false);

    </script>
```

---

webpage:
http://www.qurantour.com/car/index.html

zip:
http://www.qurantour.com/car/car.zip

i have tried the following code, but it still seems to reload/flicker page on
mobile device

```
        <style>
        .svg-container {
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }

        @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
          .svg-container {
            background: url('car1-landscape.svg') // set correct path here
          }
        }
        @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
          .svg-container {
            background: url('car1-portrait.svg') // set correct path here
          }
        }

        </style>


        <div class="svg-container"></div>


        i have tried above, but page still seems to reload when i scroll up, 
        anything else i can try please

        thankyou

    <style>

    .svg-container-landscape,
    .svg-container-portrait {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .svg-container-landscape {
        background: url(car1-landscape.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      }
    .svg-container-portrait {
        background: url(car1-portrait.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      }
    @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
      .svg-container-portrait {
        opacity:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
      .svg-container-landscape {
        opacity:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }

    </style>

    <html>
    <div class="svg-container-landscape"></div>
    <div class="svg-container-portrait"></div>
    </html>
```

Comment: have you considered using media queries for orientation and using a div background url to switch between the 2 svgs ?

Comment: how can i do this with code, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

To change the svg dynamically, try using css like below instead of reloading the content.

in HTML add the following container for the svg

```
<div class="svg-container-landscape"></div>
<div class="svg-container-portrait"></div>
```

in CSS add the svg as background

```
.svg-container-landscape,
.svg-container-portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity:1;
}
.svg-container-landscape {
    background: url('car1-landscape.svg') // set correct path here
    background-repeat: no-repeat; //if needed
  }
.svg-container-portrait {
    background: url('car1-portrait.svg') // set correct path here
    background-repeat: no-repeat; //if needed
  }
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  .svg-container-portrait {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .svg-container-landscape {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Keeping both the svg in dom to prevent flicker on rotation, which happens when the new image is loaded and used to replace the other image. Now with opacity, both images would be loaded, but only one would be showed. You could test with `display:none` and `display:block` too

Comment: i tried (new css code above) but still page is reloading flickering

Comment: The problem could be the page trying to load the new image from the internet when orientation changes

Comment: hi i have tried the code above but nothing seems to appear in the window, could you please properly test this code

Comment: try adding an opacity: 1 outside as above